# Preg_match Help. Cannot Read String from Email. 

Tags: php, regex, email

I have a script that is reading emails and pulling information out of the email and saving it to my sql database. However, it does not insert any information pertaining to phone numbers.

This is my code to determine the Phone Number:

```
if (preg_match('|^<b>Phone(.*)>\s*(\S*)<?|U', $lines[$i], $matches)) {
    $phone = trim($matches[2]);
}
```

An example email would be like this:

```
Name: Joe Schmoe

E-mail Address: joeschmoe@joeschmoe.com

Phone: 555-555-5555
```

Here is a Source Sample of what the Email provides:

```
    <b>Phone:</b> 555-555-5555</font><br> –
```

It seems the `$phone` variable ends up being empty or null as it is isn't being inserted in the database but all my other information is..

Any suggestions on this matter?

Comment: Parsing XML/HTML with regex? May want to look into [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Comment: Does all your input look like the data example? Your regex implies HTML, but the sample seems to be text based. If it is text, I'd simplify it and use `explode()`.

Comment: As long as you don't provide the actual string fragment (1:1) around that phone entry, it's hard to answer your question.

Comment: It is HTML. The email is generated by 3rd party script (No control over this email design.) The point of the script is to read and pull out the necessary information. There is additional information, but it is only the Phone field that is not being read. Would you like to see the preg match coding for the other fields to see my basic idea of what is occurring?

Comment: A question mark alone does not make a question. Please edit and make the title a real question summary.

Comment: Here is a Source Sample of what the Email provides: `<b>Phone:</b> 555-555-5555</font><br>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a cleaned up regex that should do the trick for you. It allows digit sequences to be optionally separated by either spaces or hyphens:

```php
$re = '% # Rev:20111101
    # Match phone number after "phone:</br>".
    phone:      # Literal text: "phone:".
    \s*         # Optional (zero or more) whitespace.
    </br>       # Literal text: "</br>".
    \s*         # Optional whitespace.
    (           # Capture group $1:
      [0-9]+    # {normal+} One or more digits.
      (?:       # Group for optional digit separators.
        [ -]    # {special} Digit separator.
        [0-9]+  # {normal+} More one or more digits.
      )*        # End {(special normal+)*} construct.
    )           # End $1: Phone number.
    \s*         # Optional whitespace.
    <           # Ensure number followed by literal "<".
    %ix';       // Use 'x'-free-spacing and 'i'-case-insensitive mode.
if (preg_match($re, $lines[$i], $matches)) {
    $phone = $matches[1];
}
```

### Don't use the `U` ungreedy modifier!

Using the `U` ungreedy modifier is NOT best practices - it should always be avoided. When you need to make an individual quantifier lazy, just add the `?` modifier to the specific quantifier. Note that using the `U` mode modifier is never needed or warranted - all it does is serve to confuse the reader.

**Edit 2011-11-01 3:14pm MDT** "Broke down" regex by rewriting it in free-spacing mode and added lots-o-comments.

Comment: This worked amazing! Thank you! I am still learning regex and this seemed like the best bet at first.

Comment: Do you mind breaking down your code so I have a better understanding of it?

Comment: Thanks so Much! Additional question, Do you have to convert the statement to any other format so that it is able to insert properly into a varchar(25) table? There is still a glitch with inserting into my db table and I am wondering if I might have to do an extra step such as trim() or something of the sort.

Answer (score 0):

Your first `(.*)` is matching in greedy mode - you'll probably find that ALL of the text in the string  from `Phone` onwards to the last `>` in the string has been slurped up by that capture group and is in `$matches[1]`.

Does the `<b>` in the pattern indicate you're working on an HTML string? You shouldn't use regexes on HTML, as they can/will blow up on you. Use [DOM](http://php.net/dom) instead to find the phone number node, and then extract the node's text content. YOu can then use a simple substring expression to split the phone number text into `Phone:` and `555-555-5555`.

Comment: I am not that familiar with DOM, do you have any suggestions or examples of how this would work to get that String of numbers?

Answer (score 0):

I would try something more reliable without html tags involved

|\bPhone:\s+(\S*)|